# detener formulario cuando active mensaje alert

Tags: javascript, php

cordial saludo

estoy haciendo una validacion para que un campo tipo textarea tenga un minimo de 20 caracteres y un maximo de 888.
esta validacion ya me funciona, requiero que cuando me muestre la alerta el formulario no avance, sino que se ubique en campo. he realizado el siguiente codigo.
gracias por la ayuda

```html
<script Language="JavaScript">
function validar(texto){

    if (texto.length <20){ //si el texto es menor a 2
        alert('Motivo no es sufientemente descriptivo');
          obsmotan.focus();
          return (false);
    }
    else if (texto.length >888){ //si el texto es mayor a 888
        alert('Motivo es sufientemente descriptivo');
          obsmotan.focus();
          return (false);
    }
    
}
</script>

<form action="registro.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Observacion &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <textarea name="obsmotan" cols="35" rows="2" id="obsmotan" ></textarea>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
           <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Guardar" onClick="validar(obsmotan.value);"  />
        </th>  
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Si requieres hacer el con JS necesitas un eventListener, para este caso el click del boton submit, una vez con eso pasa el 'event' en la función y has el preventDefault addEventListener('click', (e)=>{ e.preventDefault() })

Comment: gracias, ajuste el codigo segun lo sugerido y me funciono   `<script Language="JavaScript">
function validar(texto){

 if (texto.length <20){ //si el texo es menor a 2
  alert('Motivo no es sufientemente descriptivo');
                event.preventDefault();
 }
 else if (texto.length >888){ //si el texo es mayor a 8
  alert('el texto es muy largo');
                event.preventDefault();
 }
 
}

</script>`